# Big Blue Button version 0.81 Sever Setup and Devlopment from source code

Tags: bigbluebutton

** I have already download Big Blue Button VM image and successfully execute it **.

- Now I want to build Big Blue Button from source code, setup my own big blue button server and compile each and every module like a real developer.
- I already surf the problem in the Big Blue Button official website. I got some links which are helpful. But hardly managed to get the appropriate link.
- It will be helpful if anybody provide me appropriate instruction for setup and run Big Blue Button from source code.

> Note: I am working for Big Blue Button version 0.81.